# JAX WS xsd:any type is an XMLSchema element

Tags: web-services, xsd, jax-ws, any

Handling  xsd:any type is an XMLSchema element JAX WS

```
<types>
<schema targetNamespace="http://www.iona.com/artix/wsdl"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
<complexType name="unmappedType">
<sequence>
<xsd:any namespace="##other"
processContents="skip"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
<element name="request" type="tns:requestType"/>
</schema>
</types>
```

The  xml is there as a STring how to have it as a  document object, and then  transfer its contents into a SOAPElement instance

Need guidance for the implementation and client code.

Convertng the XML String into the Element. and also reading it back once the response is received .

Answer (score 2):

I see that someone has downvoted your question... If you don't mind, I would first point out the issues your question seems to have: the snippet most likely comes from an WSDL, but the schema is rather invalid. The first thing you should do is to make it right. Maybe something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--W3C Schema generated by QTAssistant/W3C Schema Refactoring Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<schema targetNamespace="http://www.iona.com/artix/wsdl" xmlns:tns="http://www.iona.com/artix/wsdl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <complexType name="unmappedType">
        <sequence>
            <any namespace="##other" processContents="skip"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <element name="request" type="tns:unmappedType"/>
</schema>
```

Once you've done it, I suggest making up an XML that looks the way you want; make sure you validate that. Post it along with your question...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://www.iona.com/artix/wsdl">
    <any_element xmlns="otherNS">anyType</any_element>
</request>
```

I would then use a tool that's free and easy to use when it comes to JAXB (I recommend [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/), it has a straightforward interface). Then write a small Java console app that uses your code; debug through, and see what you get when you unmarshall the XML. Maybe read a little bit the documentation, and then eventually post to ask for help with a more specific question.

The xsd:any and JAXB is pretty well documented: try this about [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/faq/index.html#dom_bind)...